# What's the wrong with this HTML5 , Javascript slider code?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a slider example with HTML5 and Javascript but the code doesn't work

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function slider_change(val){
        document.getElementById('slider_value').innerHtml=val;
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="50"
    step="2" onChange="slider_change(this.value)" />
<br/><br/>
Slider value :  <span id="slider_value" >50</span>
```

appears the slider but no change in the inner HTML of the span .

Comment: Just do yourself a favor and check your browser console when you have unexpected results

Comment: Works great if you fix the typo: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NYSc9/. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is called `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`

Answer (score 1):

Good to see you have done everything right except `innerHTML` .. replace `innerHtml by innerHTML`